# Changing the dimensions of a BitMapImage in WPF, and what kind of objects can I put in an <Image> element?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, bitmapimage

I am trying to create an explorer app with a `TreeView` element, and have different icons for each level of the tree, and following the article here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21248/A-Simple-WPF-Explorer-Tree

It is all working great, except that I want to have different **sized** icons as well.

My `XAML` for the Image element is here:

```
<Image Name="img"
       Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
       AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},
       Path=Header,
       Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"
/>
```

The piece of code that decides which icon to return is here:

```
if ((value as string).Contains(@"\""))
{
    Uri uri = new Uri ("pack://application:,,,/Images/DeployWiz_Network.png");
    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);

    return source;
}
```

How would I change the dimensions of the image being returned? Changing the dimensions of a bitmapimage object doesn't seem to work. What other image objects could I return as the  source?

Comment: Why not simply set the `Width` and `Height` of the `Image` control?

Comment: Because depending on what level of the tree you are in, I want that to be different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my question. Jeez, what a dummy. Below is the code I changed that got me the results I wanted:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/DeployWiz_Network.png");
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.UriSource = uri;
source.DecodePixelHeight = 10;
source.DecodePixelWidth = 10;
source.EndInit();

return source;
```

Comment: You should not set both of `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` as that may spoil the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: @Dbloom: decodePixelHeight and Decodepixelwidth property doesn't work in windows 8 though it work in windows 7 and windows 10.

Comment: newer version of `BitmapImage` no longer have `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()`.

Comment: To clarify: `BegInit()` and `EndInit()` are still on `BitmapImage` as of net6 (and net48).